# hamburger doesn't toggle if drawer is not opened previously

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout, navigation-drawer

i have a v7 Toolbar inside an AppBarLayout and when i try to toggle it from the hamburger icon it does not toggle the drawer unless i open it swiping it, after this the hamburguer works properly.

The code below contains the Layout content and the toolbar related code inside onCreate:

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

```java
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);    
drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();
```

also i've tried to make it work adding a NavigationOnClickListener by myself and, although it prints the Log it does not open the drawer (i've tried it with and without the syncState() call):

```java
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i(TAG, "OPEN");
                toggle.syncState();
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check these codes and if you haven't include them yet, try them:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    toggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    toggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

Other than onCreate, these codes are also needed per [the official reference](https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html).

Comment: Hello Hata, I already have those on my code and it does not work :(